# libGDX Project Generator showing "Build Failed" everytime I try Generating a project

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, game-engine, game-development

I am trying to install libGDX on my machine using the libGDX Project Setup and have set the location to everything it needs.But everytime I click "Generate",I get this Error:

```
Generating app in C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\test
Executing 'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\test/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon'
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\test\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\lenovo\.gradle\caches\7.5.1\scripts\2e5ewf69m4vwrhf5dztt0u5q6).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Done!
To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> Gradle -> Existing Gradle Project
To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> build.gradle
To import to NetBeans: File -> Open Project...
Generating app in C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\test
Executing 'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\test/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon'
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\test\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\lenovo\.gradle\caches\7.5.1\scripts\2e5ewf69m4vwrhf5dztt0u5q6).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Done!
To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> Gradle -> Existing Gradle Project
To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> build.gradle
To import to NetBeans: File -> Open Project...
Generating app in C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\test
Executing 'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\test/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon'
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\test\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\lenovo\.gradle\caches\7.5.1\scripts\2e5ewf69m4vwrhf5dztt0u5q6).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Done!
To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> Gradle -> Existing Gradle Project
To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> build.gradle
To import to NetBeans: File -> Open Project...
```

I have tried searching everywhere but I am having difficulty getting this to work. I am very new to this and any help will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in "Unsupported class file major version 63".

Java class file version 63, is java jdk 19, so it is complaining that the class files have been compiled for java version 19, but you are using a version which is smaller then version 19.